# How to use ussd services in ubuntu

Tags: ussd

I am totally new to Ubuntu linux. I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my pc. I use modem D-Link DWM-156 with my pc. I dont know how to use ussd services in ubuntu. I've heared about modem-manager gui. SMS is working nicely with this app but when i send a code like *123# for bsnl, i get a 3-words error: Time-Out Limit Reached. This happens for all sims like idea.

Prepaid Manager also not working. Also, many utilities like gammu, gsm-ussd, etc not working for me. The same happens when i use MMX353G modem.
Please guide me how to use ussd in ubuntu. Please tell step by step as i am entirely new to ubuntu. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.